# Anti-aliasing filter as notch and lowpass

Tags: analog, filter, low-pass, aliasing

In order to reach a steep attenuation for an analog antialiasing filter, there are issues if a high Q notch filter is followed by a low order lowpass filter (or vice versa)? The notch resonance could make a brickwall filter near the cutoff frequency while the low pass would handle the higher part of the spectrum.

Comment: No this wouldn't work how you expect - have you tried superimposing a notch response with a low pass response and drawing the resultant combined frequency response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in essence is exactly how an elliptic filter works.

Most filter design packages that will design 'normal' Butterworth and Chebychev filters will also design elliptic filters, these have a Cheby passband, with added zeroes in the stopband.

If you try to randomly add zeroes to an existing low pass response, you probably won't get the response you want. If you do the proper elliptic design, then you get to choose the passband ripple and the stopband attenuation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to making a brickwall filter. A high-Q notch will indeed provide a steep cutoff, but it will by its nature have a very narrow rejection band, followed by an equally steep high-pass function. Since the rejection band is narrow, it won't do a whole lot to improve the function of the low-pass.